# getting the latest records from mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database with several records. each record has an name. It is not unique , meaning that the same name appears many times in the table as the values are updated.
How can i create a query that will return only the **latest** names that were updated over the last 5 min. (every name is updated many times per minute. I want only the latest entry within the 5 min window)

Comment: That's good. Can you edit your question and tell us that? Do you have the table structure? Can you post us the `SHOW CREATE TABLE yourtable` output? Help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a `TIMESTAMP` column, you should be able to get the newest for a name that was added in the past 5 minutes by doing a query like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable AS a
WHERE a.ts = 
    (SELECT MAX(ts)
     FROM yourtable AS b
     WHERE b.ts > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
       AND b.name = a.name)
```

Attempt #2:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable AS a
INNER JOIN (SELECT name, MAX(ts) AS ts
     FROM yourtable
     GROUP BY name
     HAVING MAX(ts) > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) AS b
 ON a.name = b.name
AND a.ts = b.ts
```

Comment: this worked! but it took 6sec for mysql to proccess. And there are few records there... is there a quicker method?

Comment: i dont understand the part  AND b.name = a.name

Comment: I missed the MySQL bit... in my experience, MySQL is not the greatest performer when sub-queries are involved.  I added a potential second method, but I don't have something to test it with, so it's not guaranteed to work.

Comment: `b.name = a.name` cause the sub-query to be a correlated sub-query.  For each record in the outer query (a, in this case), you perform the query on the inner query (b).  You can read about them in MySQL here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html

Comment: @redfrogsbinary: 6 seconds for few records is slow (how many are "few"?). You can post the indexes you have here or in a new question for speed optimization.

Comment: few is about 2500 records. is it few?!

Answer (score 4):

You should add a [column with a `TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html) to your table.

This column will automatically be initialised and updated to the current time when the row gets changed, so taking all the columns that changed the last X minutes then becomes a simple query.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE yourtimestamp  > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
```

Without such a column, you can't really know when a row has been changed, unless you find another way to track changes. A trigger or the binary log could help, but both solutions are not easier and certainly not faster than adding a column.

Comment: I think this may only partly answer the question. The OP likely wants only that record that was last updated

Comment: the above code will display every record that was updated within the 5min. I want only the most recent updated within the 5min

Comment: The most recent per what? Per user? Do a GROUP BY user and get the MAX(yourtimestamp). Or have your trigger INSERT-ON-DUPLICATE-UPDATE into another table that HAS the proper UNIQUE KEYs.

Answer (score 1):

Have a `TIMESTAMP` column for your table. Select only the records where the time-stamp value is between five minutes ago and now (See [Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for further info). Optionally group by name and select the row with maximum time-stamp value if you only want the latest update for every name.